# How to extract certain strings from a column in a csv file?

Tags: python, r

The csv file I was given has a column that is kinda messy. I want to be able to collect all the departments/institutes (e.g. Department of Y1, College of X2, and College of X3), so I can count how many unique institutions there are in my file.

Sample data from csv file is shown below:

```
Name           Affiliation
Anna           Faculty of X1, Department of Y1, Z1 University, City A, Country 1
Isabela        Institute of W1, College of X2, Department of Y2, University of Z2, Country 1
Wally          Institute of W2, College of X3, Department of Y2, University of Z2, Country 1
```

and this goes on for thousands of rows.

My goal is to have something like a dataframe that contains a column with said unique institutions. Is there a way to do this using Rstudio (preferably) or python?

Comment: What do you consider as an `institution`?  I'm finding hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Marie, welcome to SO! Could you include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? And check out [`separate()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html) from the `tidyr` package in R. It might be what you are looking for.

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you just need `unique(df$Affiliation)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using the `stringr` package in R.

```
library(stringr)
TargetPrefixes <- c("Faculty", "Department", "Univrsity", "College", "Institute")
split <- str_split(data$Affiliation,",")
split <- unlist(split)
trim <- str_trim(split,side = "both") 
matches <- sapply(trim,function(x){Reduce(`|`,(str_detect(x,TargetPrefixes)))})
result <- unique(trim[matches])
result
[1] "Faculty of X1"    "Department of Y1" "Institute of W1"  "College of X2"    "Department of Y2" "Institute of W2"  "College of X3"
```

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(Name = c("Anna", "Isabela", "Wally"), Affiliation = c("Faculty of X1, Department of Y1, Z1 University, City A, Country 1", 
"Institute of W1, College of X2, Department of Y2, University of Z2, Country 1", 
"Institute of W2, College of X3, Department of Y2, University of Z2, Country 1"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```